# Manga where a girl becomes the villain in a novel she is reading, who is secretly female

Tags: story-identification, manga

The story from what I remember is that a girl is reading a cliché novel with the male lead protecting the female lead from the villain, and the villain dies in the end. Something happens and the girl becomes the villain and realizes the villain was actually a girl and "his" family tells "him" to hide the fact from everyone. The male lead finds out "he" is a she, but keeps the secret and gets closer to the villain than the female lead.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When and where did you read this?  Do you remember any character or place names or any notable details of the art (character or scene)?

Answer (score 1):

This is *[Accidentally Reborn as an Evil Crossdressing Woman](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/accidentally-reborn-as-an-evil-crossdressing-woman)*. It is licensed by Coolmic.

> "You're... a woman?!" The evil prince who was my favorite character in an otome game is actually a crossdressing girl?! Is... this the start of the love story between the male lead of the game and the cross-dressing evil prince (♀)?

The story the protagonist is reading before she dies is an otome game on her smartphone, not a novel. The scene she's reading is as described in the question; the main villain of the story is threatening the female lead.

[image: Opening scene of the manga, showing the otome game]

While reading it, she's hit by a promotional truck for the game and wakes up as the villain. She quickly discovers that she is still a woman, which is never mentioned in the game, and the male lead finds out as well.

Several chapters later she finds a letter from her grandfather, mentioning that her family has a surplus of daughters and lack of sons, and she was disguised as a man in order to allow her to attend an academy and gain honor for her family.

[image: Raised as a man so she could attend the academy]

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tag combination `Reincarnated as the Villain/ess` and `Cross-dressing`.